# Displaying Tab bar from second screen in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

In delegate class I wrote the code as follows

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 [self generateFirstScreen];
 [self removeFirstScreen]; // On login check implement this method or u can directly            write the snippet here as well.
[self prepareControllersOnTabs];  //your tab controller code function
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
-(void) removeFirstScreen
{
[firstScreen removeFromSuperView];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[firstScreen release];
}
-(void) generateFirstScreen
{ 
FirstScreen *firstScreen = [[FirstScreen alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstScreen animated:YES];
[firstScreen release]; 
}
```

but generateFirstScreen works fine but removeFirstScreen gives an exception Please help me.

Comment: what is your actual requirement..

Comment: My actual requirement is First screen with out tab bar control and from second screen onwards tab bar will come .Thanks in advance

Comment: come to this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8469/room-for-andhra-pradesh-mobile-developers

Comment: Hi Narayana I didnt find where to give reply to you

Comment: My FirstScreen is with.xib file

Answer (score 1):

Specify exception...

Without addSubview how can you remove it from super. Do you want to use popViewController.?

Again you are allocating firstScreen only once & releasing it twice..!

Comment: As BobDev said you can remove view only if you have added it. If you want to remove firstScreen which you have pushed to UINavigationController then u have to use popViewController. So i dont suggest you to write addSubview somewhere in code

Comment: Also dont release firstScreen in removeFirstScreen method coz you have released it already in generateFirstScreen method

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove a screen if you're not sure it's added to a view, otherwise you get a crash.. you can specify a tag to this view and check the subviews of the main view to check whether your view is in there somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

```
your generateFirstScreen method Change like below
FirstScreen *firstScreen = [[FirstScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstScreen" bundle:nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.objLogin];
        // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//call this metod when ever u want tabbar
-(void)tabBarControllerView
{   [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController.view setHidden:YES] ;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    self.tabBarController.view.hidden=NO;
    [window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
}
```